# Open Another Activity Using Fragment Button

Tags: java, android, button, android-fragments

Okay so I've tried two types of code to get this to work and it keeps giving me force closes when I press the button to go into another Activity. I'm using a Fragment and there's a button  in that Fragments code but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm not an experienced Android developer but I'm trying my best to learn.

Here's the Java code:

1st Method

```
public class About extends Fragment {

    Intent intent;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about, container, false);

        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Contact_Developer.class);
        final Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnContactDev);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

2nd Method

```
public class About extends Fragment {

    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about, container, false);

        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnContactDev);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Contact_Developer.class);
              getActivity().startActivity(intent);
           }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I really don't know what's going on and why I'm getting force closes but if anyone could help me and explain a little what I did wrong that'd be more than enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not handle the `onClick` for the fragment button in the Fragment. Let it go it's parent activity. And start the activity from the parent activity.

To make sure that the button `onClick` event is sent to the parent activity, make sure, in your `about.xml`, for the button with `id btnContactDev`, you have the following parameter:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btnContactDev"
  android:onClick="buttonClick"
  ...
/>
```

and in your parent activity (parent of `About` fragment), you have:

```
public void buttonClick(View v) {
  switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnContactDev:
      Intent myIntent = new Intent();
      myIntent.setClassName(your_package_name_string, your_activity_name_string);
      // for ex: your package name can be "com.example"
      // your activity name will be "com.example.Contact_Developer"
      startActivity(myIntent);
    break;
  }
}
```

HTH.

PS: This solution is very specific for what your requirement. In general, it's best to handle the `onClick` events related to the fragment inside the fragment class.

PS: Yes, as the other solution says, make sure you have registered the `Contact_Developer` Activity in your `Manifest` file.

Comment: I changed it but what do I do with new View.OnClickListener? It's giving me an error saying to add Unimplemented Method. The other error is Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Contact_Developer.class); when I hover over it its telling me "Remove arguments to match intent" when I click it I get this Intent myIntent = new Intent(); What should I do? I appreciate the help

Comment: You don't need View.OnClickListener if you implement it the way i have said. And for Intent error, i have edited the code - pls look at it.

Comment: Okay for the your_package_name_string and your_activity_name_string what do I actually put in there? The package names? Because I've tried that and it gave me some error. Those are the only two things I don't get

Comment: @Kodi Look at the code above [edited answer]. I have given example what you need to use for package and activity names. Replace com.example with appropriate package name that's right for you.

Comment: @VJVélanSolutions - i have mentioned like this in my Fragment class:
String packageName="package com.example.lap254.tutorpay";
String className="com.example.lap254.tutorpay.ViewCustomersList";

Comment: And, I am trying to open activity from a fragment :
button_ViewCustomers_List.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.View_Customers_List:
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                        myIntent.setClassName(packageName,className);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                        break; }

Comment: @VJVélanSolutions - I am also a beginner and trying to learn coding. Please can you tell me why the error is throwing and I have followed your solution in my coding!

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the proper activity in the AndroidManifest.xml? Each activity other then the first should be declared inside the application tag, like this:

```
<activity
   android:name=".Contact_Developer"
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

If it's not found, it will give force close.

Comment: Where in the Manifest do I put this? Below <activity
        android:name="your.package.MainActivity"? I already have Contact_Developer in the Manifest should I put the code in anyways?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that the activity is not ready.

I would not recommend you following harikris's solution even though it works. It's usually bad practice to put code (`onClick()` which handles the click event) in your XML file. For example, it will be very difficult to hunt that piece of code down to review/ change it in the future yourself, not to mention another developer in your team.

I'd suggest to listen to the event the activity is ready i.e. `onActivityCreated()` within your Fragment class. Override the implementation of the same method and call something in your activity e.g. onFragmentReady() like in the example below.

**Fragment class**:

```
public class About extends Fragment {

    Intent intent;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about, container, false);

        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Contact_Developer.class);
        final Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnContactDev);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
        public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            ((MyActivity) this.getActivity()).onFragmentReady();
        } 
}
```

**Activity class**:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private void onFragmentReady() {
        Log.i(TAG, "testing");
         intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Contact_Developer.class);
         final Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnContactDev);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public class About extends Fragment {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `getContext()` or `getApplicationContext()` instead of `getActivity()`
so code will be 
`Intent intent =new Intent(getContext(),Contact_Developer.class);
startActivity(intent);`