# Kotlin : How to navigate from Fragment to activity

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to navigate from Fragment to activity with a button click .

I 've searched so many times online ,but still not able to resolve the problem ..

My app crash with the below code ,could anyone take a look what was going on please ?

Thank you so much in advance !

```
package com.gearsrun.www.UI.Home.fragment

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup


import com.gearsrun.www.R
import com.gearsrun.www.UI.Sunflower.SunflowerAvailableActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_profile.*

class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)

          btn_log_out.setOnClickListener {
              activity?.let {
                  val intent = Intent(it,SunflowerAvailableActivity::class.java)
                 it.startActivity(intent)
              }
          }
        return v
    }




}
```

Comment: Make sure you include the stack trace so we can see what caused the crash and what line it occurred on.

Comment: @YellowClock If you won't share your stack trace or explain the circumstances that trigger the crash, you're just going to get wild guesses like you have so far that have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Hi my friend ,I am new in kotlin , I had inserted the breakpoint at the btn_log_out.setOnClickListener  ,thank you so much "2021-07-25 /? E/Zygote: GL_OOM reserved vma failed, errno:22
2021-07-25 /? I/om.gearsrun.ww: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-07-25 /? E/om.gearsrun.ww: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x28000
2021-07-25 /? I/AntivirusLog: OppoLog, sQELogOn = false, sQELogOnMTK = false
2021-07-25 /? E/ColorAntiVirusBehaviorManager: failed to get ColorAntiviruManagerService
2021-07-25/? E/RefClass: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

Comment: @Tenfour04 Hi my friend ,thank you so much for your kind advise , I had solved the problem now with the help of lets starts coding , I am very thankful for all of your kindness and patience ! God bless you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you didn't tell what btn_log_out really is?

**EDIT:**

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)
        try{
        //you need to be specific
        val logoutBtn : Button = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_log_out)
        // now use logoutBtn
          logoutBtn.setOnClickListener {
              activity?.let {
                  val intent = Intent(it,SunflowerAvailableActivity::class.java)
                 it.startActivity(intent)
              }
          }} catch(e:Exception){
Log.e("ProfileFragmentError", " Error", e)
}
        return v
    }
```

I believe this should work, if not try replacing activity in above code with context or requireContext() or requireActivity.

Comment: Hi my friend ,thank you so much for your recommendation . I have followed your suggestion ,but my app still crash ..  Could you please send me a demo ?Thank you so much for your patience

Comment: @YellowClock can you post the error message you are getting here.

Comment: @Tenfour4 I believe he didn't declare what exactly he's setting setOnClickListener on and that's why his app must've been crashing.

Comment: @letsstartcoding : hi my friend ,yes ,the error is "021-07-25 21:42:28.877 6790-6790/? E/Zygote: GL_OOM reserved vma failed, errno:22
2021-07-25 21:42:28.886 6790-6790/? I/om.gearsrun.ww: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-07-25 21:42:28.916 6790-6790/? E/om.gearsrun.ww: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x28000
2021-07-25 21:42:28.932 6790-6790/? I/AntivirusLog: OppoLog, sQELogOn = false, sQELogOnMTK = false
2021-07-25 21:42:28.932 6790-6790/? E/ColorAntiVirusBehaviorManager: failed to get ColorAntiviruManagerService
2021-07-25 /? E/RefClass: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

Comment: @Yellow Clock you need to filter your logcat the error messages you've sent here, I believe, are mostly of background apps not of the actual app you are running.

Comment: @YellowClock try the above code and in the logcat filter by using **ProfileFragmentError** and post the error here

Comment: @letsstartcoding Hiii my friend ,you saved me !! You are right ,what you said works !!!! Thank you soooo much for you patience ,and hard effort ,god bless you !!

Comment: @YellowClock No problem. I believe if you are starting just now try going through [google codelabs](https://developer.android.com/courses/kotlin-android-fundamentals/overview), this helped me a lot when I was starting with android kotlin. Have a Nice Day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it as normal as
Delete that "actvitivy?.let"

Replace " it " with "context"
And start the activity

Comment: Hi my friend ,I have tried what you recommened ,my app still crash .. could you please show me a demo that can run ? Thank you so much for your patience !

Comment: I think may be you add View object inside the onClickListener  .... And refer this too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735723/open-another-activity-using-fragment-button

Comment: Thank you so much bro ,but this demo is for Java , and I need it with kotlin .. Do you have a kotlin example ?

Comment: @YellowClock This is enough info for you to read and understand 90% of Java code if you know Kotlin: 1) Variable and function declarations start with the type instead of `fun`, `val` or `var` before the name. 2) Constructor calls have the `new` keyword before them when they are called. 3) Instead of `:` to show what a class extends or implements, the keywords `extends` or `implements` are used. 4) Functions that return nothing return `void` instead of `Unit`.

Comment: @Tenfour04  I am new in kotlin ,please let me know if I did wrong ,and I will correct it  ,thank you so much for your patience!