# startActivity() is reloading same activity instead of starting the new one

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, start-activity

UPDATE: ROOKIE ERROR. I had not changed my frag type to 'MenuFragment', it was still 'LoginFragment' from the other activity. Yes i copied and pasted over and didn't check properly.. Thank you everyone for your help.

I am creating a simple 'login' screen for an assignment and cannot seem to start my next activity. The 'login' button is simply meant to read the username and password text that has been input and if correct, start the 'MenuActivity'. Instead, it simply restarts the same activity (or at least does the animation as if the activity has restarted).

I am calling startActivity() from a fragment, but I believe my syntax is correct there.

Here is the code.

Main Fragment onCreateView method

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

        // get references for all major ui elements
        welcomeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.welcomeText);
        username = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);
        password = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.pinEditText);
        loginButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                // if username and password are in the user list
                if(dataset.userLogin(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()))
                {
                    // change activity to main menu activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MenuActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Error: Username or password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pracgrader">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PracGrader">
        <activity
            android:name=".MenuActivity"
            android:exported="true" />


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Menu Activity:

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        // assign login fragment
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        LoginFragment frag = (LoginFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.menuFragmentContainer);
        if(frag == null)
        {
            frag = new LoginFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.menuFragmentContainer, frag)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Menu fragment:

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

    private Dataset dataset;

    private Button userListButton;
    private Button practicalListButton;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public MenuFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment MenuFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MenuFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MenuFragment fragment = new MenuFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        dataset = Dataset.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

        userListButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.userListButton);
        practicalListButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.practicalListButton);

        userListButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

            }
        });

        practicalListButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Please suggest any further code you wish to see. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you check logs to see if there is any crash or error in logout while launching the activity.

Comment: No errors or crashes unfortunately

Comment: Please provide code of MenuActivity as well

Comment: share here your MenuActivity.class.

Comment: share here your MenuActivity.class

Comment: menuactivity code added

Comment: are you sure that frag is not null in MenuActivity , because if not it will be added again, and you will see login screen once more, just as you mentioned

Comment: After pressing the login button , you opened Menu Activity , which inflates the LoginFragment, Shouldn't it be MenuFragment as you just came from login

Answer (score 1):

[Open Another Activity Using Fragment Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735723/open-another-activity-using-fragment-button)
you can check this link for elaborated answers
further more you can override OnViewCreated on Fragment by simply implementation then you can call click listener there like the example i am posting the code below it will 100% work.
**step 1)**  @Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
init(view);
onClickListener();

Comment: I have posted the best approach for your answer and then in onclick listener method you can post your code inside it, it will work definatelty
thankyouuu!